# Reading file unicode and converting to english Python

Tags: python-3.x, encode, readlines

Im currently having some troubles reading a file with Python 3. When I open the file as plain text, I can read the following text:

> sadfdasfsafasdf,asdfdasfdsafdasfdasf,asdfasfasddfa,asfdasfadd

However when I read the file with the following code (I used these lines to read other text files and it worked, so not sure why this specific text file is doing that):

```
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines() 
    return content
```

I get the unicode:

> ÿþs\x00a\x00d\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00s\x00a\x00f\x00a\x00s\x00d\x00f\x00,\x00a\x00s\x00d\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00d\x00s\x00a\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00,\x00a\x00s\x00d\x00f\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00a\x00s\x00d\x00d\x00f\x00a\x00,\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00a\x00d\x00d\x00\n

and if I print it, it automatically converts the unicode to readable characters, however it adds two characters:

```
print(content)
```

> ÿþs a d f d a s f s a f a s d f , a s d f d a s f d s a f d a s f d a
>   s f , a s d f a s f a s d d f a , a s f d a s f a d d

So Im a bit confuse of how to be able to encode this text, so that I can read the original one and not the unicode. I tried to encode('utf-8'), ('latin1')... but for example with utf-8 it simply  adds b'' around the unicode and converts the two extra characters.

> b'\xc3\xbf\xc3\xbes\x00a\x00d\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00s\x00a\x00f\x00a\x00s\x00d\x00f\x00,\x00a\x00s\x00d\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00d\x00s\x00a\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00,\x00a\x00s\x00d\x00f\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00a\x00s\x00d\x00d\x00f\x00a\x00,\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00d\x00a\x00s\x00f\x00a\x00d\x00d\x00\n'

So I wonder how to correctly read the text and what is the concept that Im mixing here.